# Определение предиката

Tags: синтаксис

*(1) Я здесь не при чем.*

*(2) Лучше бы я умер.*

Помогите, пожалуйста, определить сказуемое в этих двух предложениях. К сожалению не могу предложить свою версию...

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

> *(1) Я здесь не при чем.*

Правильнее было бы  —  в соответствии с рекомендациями словарей (см., к примеру, [**"Русский орфографический словарь"**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC&all=x))  —  вместо ***не*** использовать здесь частицу ***ни***:

*Я здесь **ни при чём**.*

Сказуемое в этом предложении составное именное, именная часть выражена лексическим фразеологизмом  ***ни при чём***.

Ср. [[**Грамматика-80**]](http://rusgram.narod.ru/2661-2673.html):

> **§ 2661.**  <…>
>
> 3) В позиции сказуемого или главного члена предложения нормальны также
>   лексические фразеологизмы с *ни: нипочем, **ни при чем**, ни к чему:*
>
> *Урожай тут **ни при чем…***
>
> *Ни я, ни ты тут **ни при чем.***

===

> *(2) Лучше бы я умер.*

А вот для определения сказуемого в этом предложении нужно, по-моему, знание контекста, в котором это предложение было использовано .

Если предложение произносится с ударением на последнем слове, то сказуемым в нём будет сочетание ***лучше бы умер***  —  простое глагольное сказуемое, осложнённое частицей ***лучше бы.***

Ср. [[**М. А. Шелякин "Русскии инфинитив: (морфология и функции) : учебное пособие"**]](https://books.google.ru/books?id=3NoLAQAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%22&dq=%22%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9r4GEo6_PAhUHWCwKHcD3DQ4Q6AEIHDAA):

> Частица ***лучше бы*** вносит значение усиленного желания
>   предпочтительного действия вместо реального: *Лучше бы мне не ходить
>   туда //Лучше бы я не ходил туда. Лучше бы ему остаться жить в деревне
>   // Лучше бы он остался ...*

Но произноситься рассматриваемое нами предложение может и с ударением на "***я***":

***Лучше*** бы **Я** умер (а не кто-то другой, чья жизнь для *МЕНЯ* была дороже своей).

В этом случае частица ***лучше*** будет входить, имхо, в состав подлежащего, сказуемым же будет  сочетание ***умер бы***  —  простое глагольное сказуемое в форме условного наклонения.

Answer (score 0):

1) **Я здесь ни при чем**. Сравнить: (1) Я здесь (был) не при чем (глагольная связка  в прошедшем времени).

**Сказуемое составное именное**, связка БЫТЬ в настоящем времени пропущена, именная часть выражена местоименным сочетанием **"ни при чем"**

Примечание: Обычно используется усилительная (а не отрицательная) форма "**ни при чем**", например:
С точки зрения логики я был **ни при чем**. [Юрий Азаров. Подозреваемый (2002)]

2) **Лучше бы я умер.** Это предложение можно рассматривать как придаточную часть СПП сравнительно-сопоставительному типа, средством связи в таких СПП является компаратив ЛУЧШЕ + союз ЧЕМ, например: **Чем** гулять целыми днями, **лучше** занялся **бы** делом.

В СПП полной структуры  сопоставляются две ситуации, а в приведенном примере 
называется только одна  (вторая часть ясна из контекста).

Сказуемое (умер бы) **простое глагольное** в форме сослагательного наклонения.